# Open Graph Meta Tags with Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, share-open-graph

Im working on a site that is made with Node, vue & Nuxt, this site deal with multiples and dinamic products,  the products have a main card that is render on the fly and showed to customers, Im trying to set the  Open Graph html header meta tags dynamically to share in Whatsapp, Linkedin, Facebook and show the preview when the link is shared, But I have no success.

I put the meta in "export default" vue component area like this:

```
 head () {
    const title = (MasterKeys.ENV !== 'production' ? '[' + MasterKeys.ENV.toUpperCase() + '] ' : '') + '%s - ' + (process.env.npm_package_name || '') + this.title
    return {
      titleTemplate: title,
      meta: [
        { hid: 'og:site-name', property: 'og:site_name', content: process.env.npm_package_name },
        { hid: 'og-url', property: 'og:url', content: document.location.href },
        { hid: 'og-type', property: 'og:type', content: 'website' },
        { hid: 'og-title', property: 'og:title', content: title },
        { hid: 'og-description', property: 'og:description', content: this.description },
        { hid: 'og-image', property: 'og:image', content: this.image },
        { hid: 'twitter-card', name: 'twitter:card', content: 'summary_large_image' }
      ]
    }
  },
```

The site is configured with ssr option off in **nuxt.config.js**:

```
export default {
  ssr: false,
.
.
.
.
```

I can summarize all that I investigated:

1. In a client request Vue send to client minimum HTML, and Javascript of execute the rest of logic.
2. The client (Twitter, Facebook, etc) Open-Graph renderer does not have a Javascript engine that proccess the logic sent by nuxt in
   Javascript form.

There is a form in Nuxt - Vue to achive That?

Comment: If you want to have some nice SEO, you need to have something rendered on the server, either with SSR or SSG, both of which require `ssr: true` to be set. Otherwise, you only have a regular SPA and nothing else (basically a Vue app SEO-wise).

Comment: This is no choice for me, the application is huge and relies all of its logic on SPA, I searching  for a solution with the coexistence SPA - SSR. Is this possible?

Comment: SSG and SSR are on top of SPA because Nuxt is isomorphic. Meaning that you will get either SSG (server-side) + SPA (client-side after hydration) or SSR (server-side) + SPA (client-side after hydration). If it works in SPA, it will work with either SSR or SSG. If you want to exclude some paths and keep it only as an SPA, you can use the `exclude` key as shown here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-generate#exclude

Comment: Also nuxt.config.js file target value will be server if current value static. `target: "static"`.
details information https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-target